# Using Threading.Event to signal main thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I was reading on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829329/catch-a-threads-exception-in-the-caller-thread-in-python) about using a thread, catching an exception, and notifying the calling thread.

The answer suggested `Queue`, but in the comments it states:

> Queue is not the best vehicle to communicate an error back, unless you
>   want to have a full queue of them. A much better construct is
>   threading.Event()

From the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Event.wait):

> This is one of the simplest mechanisms for communication between
>   threads: one thread signals an event and other threads wait for it.

I'm new to multi threading and I wanted to give it a try, so I came up with this trivial example. I'm unsure if I'm on the right track.

```
import threading

def dividebyzero(event,first,second):
    try:
        result = first / second
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        event.set()
        print("Can't divide by 0")
    else:
        print(result)


e = threading.Event()
t1 = threading.Thread(name='DivideByZero',target=dividebyzero, args=(e, 10, 0),)

t1.start()
t1.join()

if e.is_set():
    print("Error occurred in division thread")
```

**Question:**

1. Using `threading.Event` as shown in my example, is it the correct way to signal the main thread an error as occurred?
2. I'm not using `event.wait()` because it seems unnecessary, I call `join()` on the `t1` thread, so when I call `is_set()` hopefully I'll get an accurate result. Is it mandatory to use `event.wait()` when using `threading.event()`
3. I understand that if I needed to raise more exceptions using an event probably isn't ideal, how would you know which exception was raise? In that situation would a `Queue` be better?

If I were to use `event.wait()` there is a chance the main thread could hang forever, because if the exception doesn't occur the event is never set.

I don't have an error or problems with the code, it works, I just want it reviewed to make sure I used `event` correctly.

Comment: This question seems, to me, on the verge of being hypothetical code, which is off-topic. The last question from the [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page is "Do I want feedback about any or all facets of the code?", which could lead to answer being pretty much "you don't need `threading` here, just call the function with the right parameters". Are you OK with that?

Comment: @Mathias Ettinger How is this hypothetical? `dividebyzero()` is a usage example, not the subject of the review.

Comment: @Coal_ Then what is the subject? `threading.Event`? Sounds like this is not OP's code, then.

Comment: @Mathias Ettinger No, using `threading.Event` to signal an exception occured. If that part was a function wrapper in a separate file and wrapped `dividebyzero()`, there would be no issue.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger - This is my code, I created a small example to describe my specific problem, using `threading.Event` to signal an exception occurred. The answer I was looking for was provided below and I checked it as the answer.

Comment: I agree with @MathiasEttinger here, however it's _example_ code. Your code is just an MVCE, and so isn't something you'd use in the wild, without adapting it each time. This can be shown by getting the same output as using `print('Error occurred in division thread')`.

Comment: @Sveta This is not code, this is hypothetical code, do you really need a thread to know that you can not divide by 0? We could advise you to not use `threading` at all, to use an `Event` as you did or a `Queue` because it is more flexible… Or even to switch to the full blown `multiprocessing` because the GIL won't let you use threads the way you intendend to. Heck, you can even `return` an exception using `multiprocessing` if you want to… Thing is, until we see your real code, we have no way (and not enough context) to know how you intend to use this "code".

Comment: @MathiasEttinger - you fail to realize what the thread is doing is not the focus of the question, the focus is how to handle an exception inside a thread and notify the main thread. I received an answer below, and gave it a check mark because it's what I wanted, not because it's the only answer, or because it was partial answered, but because it **fully** answered my question. If you want to put it on hold, delete, etc, that's your business, I got what I wanted. I'm fully aware I **shouldn't** start a thread to divide numbers, I understand that. You failed to understand what I'm really asking.

Comment: @Sveta I did realize it since the comment from Coal_ mentionning a function wrapper in a separate file. However after trying to give a shot at it, the lack of context makes it almost impossible to give proper advice about the problem at hand. This is not a code review question, this is a generic best practices or design question which may have had better reception on softwareengineering SE. The fact that you got what you wanted doesn't make it magically on-topic either: had you asked for a cooking receipe and got an answer, that I still would have redirected you to cooking SE.

Comment: In any case, when you apply what you got here to a real program, I’d certainly welcome it if you create a question about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes and no. Your approach works, and it is easy to understand. If, however, you want to keep track of what type of exception was raised, it could be improved. What if you have some super complex function that can raise 10 different exceptions, and you need access to the exception traceback if something goes wrong? You'd need 10 `threading.Event` instances. In that case, you should use a `queue.Queue` instead, which is thread-safe (untested snippet):

   ```
   import queue
   import threading

   def dividebyzero(first, second, exc_queue):
       try:
           result = first / second
       except ZeroDivisionError as exc:
           exc_queue.put(exc)
       else:
           print(result)

   excq = queue.Queue()
   t = threading.Thread(target=dividebyzero, args=(10, 0, excq))
   t.start()
   t.join()
   if excq.qsize() != 0:
       print(excq.get())
   ```
2. No, it is not mandatory to use `threading.Event.wait()`. Your observation is right: calling `event.wait()` might make the thread hang indefinitely.
3. `goto 1;`

Comment: You answered all my questions and confirmed by suspensions. Check mark coming your way.